# Consultar token mediante HTTPS

Tags: c#, post, https

Intento conectarme a la siguiente direccion para obtener un token, lo intento de las siguientes maneras, pero en todas me da error de consulta, estos son los ejemplos que uso para la consulta y las rutas como se crean:

```
string client_id = "api-stag";// CLIENT ID = api-stag
            string client_secret = "";// CLIENT SECRET = [VACIO]
            string scope = "";// SCOPE = [VACIO]
            string url = "https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token/" + "?CLIENT ID={" + client_id + "}&CLIENT SECRET={" + client_secret + "}&SCOPE={" + scope + "}";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
```

lo intente con el siguiente codigo de igual forma:

```
string client_id = "api-stag";// CLIENT ID = api-stag
            string client_secret = "";// CLIENT SECRET = [VACIO]
            string scope = "";// SCOPE = [VACIO]

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"CLIENT ID={client_id}&CLIENT SECRET={client_secret}&SCOPE={scope}");

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token");
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;
            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            string responseContent = null;

            using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
            {
                using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using (StreamReader sr99 = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        responseContent = sr99.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show(responseContent);
```

me crea los siguientes links, pero ninguno funciona, de estas maneras ni otras probadas

```
"https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token/?CLIENT ID={api-stag}&CLIENT SECRET={}&SCOPE={}"
"https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token/?CLIENT_ID={api-stag}&CLIENT_SECRET={}&SCOPE={}"
"https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token/?CLIENT_ID=api-stag&CLIENT_SECRET=&SCOPE="
"https://idp.comprobanteselectronicos.go.cr/auth/realms/rut-stag/protocol/openid-connect/token/?CLIENT_ID='api-stag'&CLIENT_SECRET=''&SCOPE=''"
```

[image: Como debe consultar por Hacienda CR]

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de que así se consume la api? porque no parece que sea el formato adecuado: https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2016/v4.1/comprobantes-electronicos-api.html

Comment: Realmente soy nuevo en esto, no se bien como consumir la API, nos brindaron la ruta anterior para pruebas (te dejo una toma de pantalla en la pregunta) a mi parecer se ejecutaba de esa manera pero el servidor me indica que la  consulta es erronea.

Comment: Ya, creo que necesitas usar alguna librería para oauth2, te dejo una respuesta a ver si te ayuda.

Comment: Esta es la librería: http://dotnetopenauth.net/

Comment: La API se debe de consultar brindada por una empresa, no es de conexión interna, lo que necesito verificar es como consumir los datos con los ejemplos brindados "Como estan en la imagen".

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que utiliza el protocolo de autorización Oauth2, y una librería que ya implemente el acceso te va a facilitar las cosas.

Comment: Tenés que afiliarte al ATV de Hacienda. Una vez afiliado y logueado, vas a necesitar un usuario y contraseña de pruebas que podés obtener en este link https://www.hacienda.go.cr/ATV/ComprobanteElectronico/frmGenerarToken_pruebas.aspx . Es bastante sencillo. Eso es para realizar el primer post que te da un token. Aquí hay un link que te puede ayudar bastante a entender el flujo, está en JAVA pero explica bien los requerimientos para lograr el flujo completo https://flecharoja.com/blog/2017-11/integracion-factura-digital/

Comment: estoy en lo mismo. Ya te funciono?